# Run Integration Tests in 1 Module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am looking to run the integrations tests found in the `androidTests` directory which is found in 1 module of a multi-module project. What is the gradle task I need to run to do this?

Comment: Probably `gradle :pathToModule:test`. `pathToModule` isn't path (in terms of system) literally. Rather module name.

Comment: try run from console `./gradlew with argument: `androidTest`, `test`or `connectedAndroidTest`